# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'label' referenced before assignment, in Kivy, Python

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I wanted to integrate this [code](https://github.com/AhmedCodor/YouTube-Tutorials/blob/master/Deep%20Focus%20Coding/Notes%20Taker/kivy_test.py) which I found to my project in kivy and replaced it with class specification, but it didn't work and gives this error. Anyone who can help I would really appreciate it. Thank you!

> ```
>  label = label(text=text_input.text)
> ```

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'label' referenced before assignment

here's my code which I tried to work with. KV:

```
       `MDBottomNavigationItem:
        name: 'screen 2'
        icon: 'calendar-month-outline'
        Label:
           id: label
           size_hint: [1, None]
           height: self.texture_size[1] + 20
           font_size: '16px'
           FloatLayout:
              size_hint: [1, None]
              pos_hint: {'center_x':.5,'center_y':.7}
              TextInput:
                 id: text_input
                 size_hint: [0.94, None]
                 pos_hint: {'top':1, 'center_x': 0.5}
                 height: 140
                 font_size: '24px'
              Button:
                 text: "Add"
                 size_hint: [None, None]
                 top: root.height - 220
                 pos_hint: {'x':.690,'y':.550}
                 size: [70, 30]
                 on_press:
                    app.add_note()
              GridLayout:
                 pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5}
                 top: root.height - 300
                 size_hint: [1, None]
                 height: 500
                 cols: 1
                 spacing: 10
                 padding: [40, 10, 40, 10]
                 id: notes_box`
```

Main.py:

```
    def add_note(self, default=''):
    text_input = self.root.get_screen('tasks').ids.text_input
    notes_box = self.root.get_screen('tasks').ids.notes_box
    if default != '':
        label = Label(text=default)
        notes_box.add_widget(label)
    else:
        if (text_input.text.strip() != ''):
            label = label(text=text_input.text)
            self.save_in_db(text_input.text)
            text_input.text = ''
            notes_box.add_widget(label)

def save_in_db(self, input_text):
    if (input_text.strip() != ''):
        with open('notes_db.txt', 'a') as db:
            db.write(input_text)
            db.write('\n')

def get_notes_from_db(self):
    lines = []
    with open('notes_db.txt', 'r') as db:
        for line in db.readlines():
            if (line):
                lines.append(line.strip())
    return lines
```

Comment: Try changing `label` with **`Label`**.

Comment: Didn't help, any other ideas?